# Save numpy 3d array as raw

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binaryfiles

My main goal is to make .raw mask from two lists of x and y values of each ROI point. Those lists are presented like this:

```py
x_vals = [94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 106, 107, 108, 108, 109, 110, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 111, 110, 109, 108, 108, 107, 106, 105, 105, 104, 104, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100, 99, 99, 99, 99, 98, 98, 98, 99, 99, 100, 100, 101, 101, 102, 103, 103, 104, 105, 105, 106, 107, 107, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 108, 107, 107, 106, 105, 105, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 119, 120, 120, 119, 118, 117, 116, 115, 114, 113, 112, 112, 112, 111, 111, 110, 110, 109, 109, 109, 109, 110, 110, 110, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 113, 113, 114, 114, 115, 115, 116, 116, 116, 117, 117, 118, 118, 117, 117, 116, 115, 114, 113, 112, 112, 111, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100, 99, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95]
y_vals = [51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 54, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 55, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 57, 58, 59, 59, 60, 61, 61, 62, 62, 63, 63, 64, 64, 64, 65, 65, 65, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 74, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 73, 73, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 71, 71, 71, 70, 69, 69, 68, 67, 66, 66, 65, 64, 63, 63, 62, 61, 61, 60, 59, 59, 58, 58, 57, 57, 56, 56, 55, 55, 54, 53, 53, 52, 52, 51, 51, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49]
```

I've already done it by making array from list:

```py
import numpy as np

def make_array_from_list(x_values, y_values):
    
    points = []
    for i in range(len(x_values)):
        tmp = []
    
        tmp.append(x_values[i])
        tmp.append(y_values[i])
    
        points.append(tmp)
    
        np_points = np.array(points)
        
    return np_points

arr = make_array_from_list(x_vals, y_vals)
```

than filling poly:

```py
def make_mask_from_points(num, shape, points):
    img = np.zeros((num, shape), np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.fillPoly(img, [points], (255, 255, 255))
    return mask

mask = make_mask_from_points(112, 162, arr1)
```

and in return my image read with this code:

```
zer = np.zeros((112, 162, 162), np.uint8)
zer[:,:,85] = mask

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def showImage(image, isGray=False):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.imshow(image, cmap = 'gray')
    plt.show()

showImage(zer[:,:,85])
```

[image: mask]

Until this point everything goes well. Now I would like to save the whole `zer` array as a .raw file (with only 1 slice being a mask). I tried doing this like that:

```py
zer.astype(np.uint8).tofile('mask.raw')
```

or simplier like that:

```py
zer.tofile('mask.raw')
```

but when I do this, after displaying it with imagej, or reading with this code:

```py
path = '/mypath/mask.raw'
size = 112
size2 = 162
imgs = 162
nbytes = 1


def readBinaryData(n,SIZE, SIZE2, H,nbytes):

     if nbytes==2:
         d = np.zeros((SIZE,SIZE2,H),np.uint16)
     elif nbytes==1:
         d = np.zeros((SIZE,SIZE2,H),np.uint8)
     else:
         print('Wrong number of bytes per voxel')
         return

     f=open(n,"rb")
     for i in range(0,H):
         for j in range(0,SIZE):
             for k in range(0,SIZE):
                 byte = f.read(nbytes)
                 if nbytes==2:
                     a = 256*byte[0] + byte[1]
                 else:
                     a = byte[0]
                 d[j,k,i] = a
     f.close()
     return d

img = readBinaryData(path, size, size2, imgs, nbytes)
```

I am getting some crazy stuff:
[image: results]
I know that this code works, and I know that imagej works, because I opened many masks with it. Now it's the first time that I need to make my own mask and I can't get over this last, final step...

Comment: We don't need the backstory. It's irrelevant and distracting. Just provide a sample array with the operations you do that don't work as expected.

Comment: The whole make_array thing is basically `np.stack((a, b), -1).ravel()`

Comment: What do you expect to be written to the file? What does `tofile` do, in your current expectation?

Comment: `np.stack((a, b), -1).ravel()` is quite different, but thank you, I will search for ready solutions. I'm expecting to get .raw file as a 8-bit image type

Comment: You're right, you don't do the `ravel` at the end